# CS0120 "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property ThePlayerOption.thePlayerChosenOption" how to fix?

Tags: c#

Here is my code, I've commented where the errors are:

```
using System;
using ScissorsPaperRock;

namespace ScissorsPaperRock
{
    public class ThePlayerOption
    {
        public UNIT thePlayerChosenOption;
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Select an option. 1 = Scissors, 2 = Paper, 3 = Rock");
            int Option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (Option == 1)
            {
                thePlayerChosenOption = UNIT.SCISSORS; // CS0120
            }
            else if (Option == 2)
            {
                thePlayerChosenOption = UNIT.PAPER; // CS0120
            }
            else if (Option == 3)
            {
                thePlayerChosenOption = UNIT.ROCK; // CS0120
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what the error wants of me, since the following code produces no errors:

```
using System;

namespace ScissorsPaperRock
{
    public class TheAIOption
    {
        public UNIT theAIChosenOption;
        void Start()
        {
            System.Random rnd = new System.Random(); // Makes the random class.
            int AISelect = rnd.Next(0, 2);
            {
                if (AISelect == 0)
                    theAIChosenOption = UNIT.SCISSORS;
                else if (AISelect == 1)
                    theAIChosenOption = UNIT.PAPER;
                else
                    theAIChosenOption = UNIT.ROCK;
                // This code SHOULD select one of the three enums in Options.cs and keep the selected option on hand.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is causing this error? And more importantly, how can I fix it cleanly?

Cheers.

Comment: Monsieur is the object not already there? Gonna need you to elaborate.

Comment: I posted my code and the exact error. UNIT is an enum and is being referenced from another file. There's no errors on the 2nd piece of code I posted, only where I commented. So what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`public UNIT theAIChosenOption;` and `public UNIT thePlayerChosenOption;` are both class members.

`void Start()` is a class method: it can freely access class members ("object instance methods").

`public static void Main()` is a STATIC class method. To access `thePlayerChosenOption` you must either:

a) provide an object reference (the gist of your error message)

... OR ...

b) declare the member STATIC: `public static UNIT thePlayerChosenOption;`

From the Microsoft documentation:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120
>
> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or
> property 'member'
>
> In order to use a non-static field, method, or property, you must
> first create an object instance. For more information about static
> methods, see Static Classes and Static Class Members. For more
> information about creating instances of classes, see Instance
> Constructors.

Here's a good article (one of many!):

[C#: Static vs Non-Static Classes and Static vs Instance Methods](https://hackernoon.com/c-static-vs-instance-classes-and-methods-50fe8987b231)

Comment: And just like that, adding "static" caused the errors to go away. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UNIT thePlayerChosenOption` variable is declared as a class variable but you're trying to access it inside a static context. Either mark `thePlayerChosenOption` as `static` or provide an object of type `ThePlayerOption` inside your `static` method. I'm also considering that your `UNIT` enum is defined somewhere else in the code.